# How to go around "AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled" on MacOSX with an M1 chip for YOLOv7

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, yolo

I am trying to train YOLOv7 off of my own dataset on a Macbook with an M1 chip. I understand CUDA works with NVIDA and that won't work on the macosx. I've tried to go around it by reinstalling anaconda3 and miniforge3 that are arm compatible but I still get this assertion error.

```
!python train.py --workers 1 --batch-size 1 --epochs 200 --img 640 640 --data data/custom_data.yaml --hyp data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --cfg cfg/training/custom_yolov7.yaml --name yolov7-output --weights yolov7.pt
```

```
YOLOR  v0.1-121-g2fdc7f1 torch 1.13.1 CPU

Namespace(weights='yolov7.pt', cfg='cfg/training/custom_yolov7.yaml', data='data/custom_data.yaml', hyp='data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml', epochs=200, batch_size=1, img_size=[640, 640], rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, notest=False, noautoanchor=False, evolve=False, bucket='', cache_images=False, image_weights=False, device='', multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, adam=False, sync_bn=False, local_rank=-1, workers=1, project='runs/train', entity=None, name='yolov7-output', exist_ok=False, quad=False, linear_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, save_period=-1, artifact_alias='latest', freeze=[0], v5_metric=False, world_size=1, global_rank=-1, save_dir='runs/train/yolov7-output11', total_batch_size=1)
tensorboard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/train', view at http://localhost:6006/
hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.1, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.3, cls_pw=1.0, obj=0.7, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.2, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, paste_in=0.0, loss_ota=1
wandb: Install Weights & Biases for YOLOR logging with 'pip install wandb' (recommended)

                 from  n    params  module                                  arguments                     
  0                -1  1       928  models.common.Conv                      [3, 32, 3, 1]                 
  1                -1  1     18560  models.common.Conv                      [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  2                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]                
  3                -1  1     73984  models.common.Conv                      [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  4                -1  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1]               
  5                -2  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1]               
  6                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]                
  7                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]                
  8                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]                
  9                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]                
 10  [-1, -3, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
 11                -1  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1]              
 12                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []                            
 13                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]              
 14                -3  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]              
 15                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 16          [-1, -3]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]                           
...
    matching_bs[i] = torch.tensor([], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.int64)
  File "/Users/yeti/opt/anaconda3/envs/yolo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 221, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

The model with train for 30 epochs, but then it'll throw this assertion error. What do you recommend I do?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/414

This resolved my issue

"Hello I was able to run with CPU now, I changed lines 786 to 791 in loss.py from device='cuda:0' to device='cpu'"

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove all the cuda dependencies. This is what fixed my issue:

For context, i am using the following version of torch on my MacOS

> torch==2.1.0

1. Firstly you have to replace `.cuda()` to `.to(device)` in all the files, (you can do it using your **IDE's replacement feature**).
2. Then, open your **build.py** and change `model.to(torch.device(cfg.MODEL.DEVICE))` to `model.to(torch.device('cpu'))`.
3. Cross check by searching in your ide to make sure that you have **removed** all the `.cuda()` operations.

The conclusion is that, you need to let your mac know that it needs to use **it's cpu and not look for cuda**.

By this time, the error should have been resolved, but if it still didn't, try setting the value of the variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in the your terminal manually:

> export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""

I hope this helps!